# What are the dangers associated with a copper sulfate CuSO4 + Water H2O solution aprox 5 gallons at room temperature in a room with no ventilation.

Tags: aqueous-solution

Will there be hazardous gases in the room? is the evaporation of this solution harmful in any way to animals or humans?

Comment: There should be no problems with evaporation/toxic off-gasing of any kind. Where did you get this solution and how concentrated is it? There should be a Safety Data Sheet if you got it from a reliable source.

Comment: The only issue I can see is that as it evaporates it will leave behind a solid residue, which when mechanically disturbed could cause dust that would be unhealthy to inhale. Just make sure you store it in a closed container.

Comment: It depends on how it is being used.  For example, dropping hot metal into the solution or electroplating at high current might cause a bit of spray in the air.

Comment: Don't drink it.

Comment: Of course there can be hazardous gases. If you are boiling the water the hot steam produced could burn you and or suffocate you depending on the rate of production. We live in a world where the SDS sheet for table salt tells you to call a poison hotline if ingested.

Comment: The solution will be for a low voltage 0.5v  copper electroplating for apron 3 moths, (open container) it will be in constant motion since we will have a magnetic stirrer,  the container will always be full of the solution or at least 3/4 of the container, any recommendations on the temperature for better results?  No intention to boil, my question is basically will the vapors leaving the container be poisonous or harmful for humans or pets? or the evaporation is simply water, leaving all the copper sulfate CuSO4 in the container as solid residue.

Comment: airhuff its Copper Sulfate Pentahydrate 99.9% Crystals + water solution,  lets say high concentration.

Comment: To have another person be notified of your comment, you need to place an at sign in front of their username, like @aafco.

Answer (score 1):

When a solution of copper(II) sulphate evaporates, the only gaseous product is water vapour. Like any ionic compound, copper(II) sulphate will be left behind as a solid residue — presumably crystalline — after water evaporation.